# If every closed subspace of a Banach space has a closed orthogonal complement, then it is a Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

My professor mentioned this fact in class.

FACT: If every closed subspace of a Banach space has a closed orthogonal complement, then it is a Hilbert space.

He mentioned that he had never seen the proof, and I am wondering what the proof is, or if I can be given a suitable reference.  Thanks!

Comment: This seems ill-posed; what could *orthogonal* complement mean in a Banach space (i.e., without knowing the norm is an inner product already)?

Comment: Yes, I certainly misspoke. The correct statement is given in the comment below by Martin Argerami.

Answer (score 4):

The correct statement is that a Banach space such all of its closed subspaces are complemented is isomorphic to a Hilbert space. It was proven by Lindestrauss and Tzafriri in 1971.

The proof is not very hard but not trivial either.

Comment: Thank you for the reference.  I am curious;  The reviewer mentions that the Lindenstrauss/Tzafriri proof is only for real Banach spaces.  Do you perhaps know if the result has been proved for complex Banach spaces?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that.