# An inner product space that every closed subspace is complemented, is it must be separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, orthonormal, separable-spaces

In a comment of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3923034/986542) someone said that

***if an inner product space satisfy that every closed subspace is complemented then it has an (countable) orthonormal basis***

and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1939088/986542) claim that

***H has a countable orthonormal basis if and only if H has a countable dense subset (which mean H is separable)***.

I trying to get the first one:take $e_1$ from $H$ such that $\||e_1\||=1$,then $E_{1} = \langle e_{1} \rangle $ is closed,so $H=E_{1}\oplus E_{1}^{\bot}$ then take $e_2$ from $H\setminus \langle e_{1} \rangle$ such that $\||e_2\||=1$ ,$E_{2}=\langle e_{1},e_{2} \rangle$ is closed,so $H=E_{2}\oplus E_{2}^{\bot}$, and so on ...... but I don't know that is it a right way to get a countable orthonormal basis of $H$.

Thanks if you can give me any advice of any form.

Comment: You misunderstood the comment you link to

Comment: @Jakobian:  So you mean that with the existence of orthogonal decompositions, the inner product space $H$ could has an orthonormal basis not necessarily countable? Could you tell me how to prove that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: For any Hilbert space $H$, each closed subspace $E\subseteq H$ is complemented. But $H$ doesn't necessarily have a countable orthonormal basis. The comment refers to if we can always find an orthonormal basis *in a dense subspace* of a Hilbert space. Turns out that the answer is yes in the separable case, and no in the non-separable case. This is what the comment answers.

Comment: @Jakobian: Sorry to bother you, I think I get what you mean, but what I'm actually confused about is why Eric says "$H$ no need to assume separability" under the comment of the first answer (in proving that $H$ is a Hilbert space).

Comment: Because the theorem given in the answer under the comment is true without assumption of separability. That is, if $K^\perp \neq\{0\}$ for any proper closed subspace $K\subseteq H$, then $H$ is a Hilbert space.